# Facebook App - no content showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am using the latest layout of facebook app. The problem is there are no content showing in my app. I have been googling for days now and hoping for some answers.

Link: https://apps.facebook.com/askbecome/

Canvas URL: http://qnawp.exava.us/sample

Can someone tell me what's the problem or what am I doing wrong?.. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using canvas?

Comment: Where's your application hosted at?

Comment: @brad: yes.. I used the sample provided in the facebook developers.

Comment: @SahilMittal: I think it's on Amazon.. why?..

Comment: @MarizPapas Okay cool can you add the **Canvas URL** to your question? More than likely if you just pasted the example and changed your app id. Then the issue is probably in the App settings on Facebook.

Comment: @MarizPapas what's the url, is it wokring if you directly open the url?

Comment: I have edited my question above and added my canvas url. It redirects to the facebook app but still no content is showing. Thanks.

Comment: @BradTheDeveloper: my app settings? I have filled all the necessary details.. What do you think I am missing?

Comment: @SahilMittal I have placed the url above since it has a facebook redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your secure canvas url isnt working:

> https://qnawp.exava.us/sample

I think you don't have the SSL certification. That's the reason that the application is not opening in the facebook iframe.

Comment: @MarizPapas I agree with Sahil Mittal's answer. Your page must be https to be viewed in Facebook.